# Sorting via table relation's in laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I have a Laravel project which has User and Order models.
User model has relation with sorting to Order model like this:

```
public function last_order() {
   return $this->hasOne('Order', 'user_id')->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->limit(1);
}
```

This returns last order for specific user. It works fine.

I need to also return sorted array of users from the newest order. I tried to do it with Eloquent on repository layer like this:

```
User::has('last_order')->with('last_order')->orderBy('last_order.created_at', 'desc')->get();
```

It doesn't work. I also tried it with sortBy method, same result. It returns me, that last_order table is not exist.

Could you advice me, how to easily sorted some like this with Eloquent (not in service layer, and without raw select)?

Thank you.

Comment: what is name of order table ?

Answer (score 1):

`sortBy()` using dot notation works fine *after* you `get()` the collection.

```
User::has('last_order')->with('last_order')->get()->sortByDesc('last_order.created_at');
```

I also noticed the `last_order()` relation is already sorted. This will not work unless you create a different relationship that doesn't limit the return to 1 and isn't pre-sorted.

Comment: Yes, you've a right . It's not work with already sorted relation. Now I found solution for this (little different access like I tried before), and I'll add it to answer. Anyway, thank you for your answer (+1)

Answer (score 0):

**It occurs to me:**

```
public function scopeLasorder($query)
{
    return $query->join(
        with(new Orden())->getTable(), 'user_id', '=', 'id' //id de User
    )->whereNotNull('last_order');
}
```

**And to execute**

```
User->lastorder->orderBy(new Orden())->getTable().'.created_at', 'desc')
```